# Children's book about a stuffed dog and stuffed cat who eat each other when their owner leaves

Tags: identification-request

I read this book a long time ago about a stuffed cat and a stuffed dog who get hungry when their owner leaves and eat each other: they rip each other apart until they are each just a rag.

They looked like this:

[image]

Comment: When did you read this exactly? In what language?

Comment: The identification of this story inspired me to [ask a new question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/13734/17) about it.

Comment: God, that's creepy

Answer (score 12):

I believe you may be thinking of the poem "The Duel", also known as "The Gingham Dog and the Calico Cat", by Eugene Field.

It's been published in many formats, with various art; for instance, this edition:

[image: cover of a version of the poem]

The poem itself goes like this (and is [in the public domain](https://poets.org/poem/duel)):

> The gingham dog and the calico cat
>   Side by side on the table sat;
>   'T was half-past twelve, and (what do you think!)
>   Nor one nor t' other had slept a wink!
>   The old Dutch clock and the Chinese plate
>   Appeared to know as sure as fate
>   There was going to be a terrible spat.
>   *(I wasn't there; I simply state*
>   *What was told to me by the Chinese plate!)*
>
> The gingham dog went "Bow-wow-wow!"
>   And the calico cat replied "Mee-ow!"
>   The air was littered, an hour or so,
>   With bits of gingham and calico,
>   While the old Dutch clock in the chimney-place
>   Up with its hands before its face,
>   For it always dreaded a family row!
>   *(Now mind: I'm only telling you*
>   *What the old Dutch clock declares is true!)*
>
> The Chinese plate looked very blue,
>   And wailed, "Oh, dear! what shall we do!"
>   But the gingham dog and the calico cat
>   Wallowed this way and tumbled that,
>   Employing every tooth and claw
>   In the awfullest way you ever saw—
>   And, oh! how the gingham and calico flew!
>   *(Don't fancy I exaggerate—*
>   *I got my news from the Chinese plate!)*
>
> Next morning, where the two had sat
>   They found no trace of dog or cat;
>   And some folks think unto this day
>   That burglars stole that pair away!
>   But the truth about the cat and pup
>   Is this: they ate each other up!
>   Now what do you really think of that!
>   *(The old Dutch clock it told me so,*
>   *And that is how I came to know.)*
>   <sub>Eugene Field</sub>